# Android Studio показывает мне ненужную информацию в диалоге проекта, как отключить?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, клавиатура

Нажал случайно какое-то сочетание горячих клавиш в Android Studio, теперь показывается ненужная информация  о дате последнего изменения и размере файлов, как отключить? Подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: Диалог проекта]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#show-tree-indent-guides

Comment: `ALT + SHIFT + /` или View -> Appearance -> Details in TreeView - снять отметку

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вам!
Но только поправка - ALT+SHIFT+\